# Accept privacy statements for Cortana

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I've installed the English (United States) language packages on my PC and I'll turn Cortana on. The problem is when I toggle it on I must accept the privacy statements but there is no button to do this.

Here is an image with the problem:

[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: I bet you have to click on "Privacy Statement" first to prove you have at least made some attempt to read it ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill: I've already done that. Has no effort.

Comment: Try to update your pc. Maby that bug is fixed in a newer version.